# How to improve speed while converting Big spatial polygon data frame to raster stack

Tags: r, rasterize

I'm working on spatial polygon data frame (spdf) dataset. This dataset contains a time series of monthly climate data. What I'm trying to achieve is to convert the spdf to raster stack with 1000m resolution for further statistical analysis. I've writen an R code but is is very slow and it took ages to convert one column.I would appreciate if any of you could suggest tips to make it faster.

```
hru<-readOGR("E:\\Tade\\HRU\\ubn_merge.shp",layer="ubn_merge") # spatial polygon
spdf<-merge(hru,spdf.2000,by.x="HRU",by.y="HRU",all.x=T,sort=F) # spdf nrow=565 ncol=375
# convert sp to raster
hru.ras<-raster(hru,resolution=1000) # raster hru shape to 1km
for (i in 1:length(spdf){
  et.ras<-rasterize(spdf,hru.ras,field=paste("m",1,sep="")) # rasterize
  et.stack<-stack(et.stack,et.ras)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In my experience you're in for a world of pain using R and the `rasterize()` function to do this task. From my testing the conversion from vector to raster is much more manageable when using the `gdal_rasterize` utilty directly.  I call it using a system call, e.g. `system(paste0("gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -l census_buffer ", census_buffer_path, " /tmp/census_mask.tif"))` etc. which obviously assumed the `gdal` utilities are in your path.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As Forrest says (and you have experienced), `rasterize` is a bit slow, but you can do much better than what you have now. You do not need to use a loop at all:

```
r <- raster(spdf, resolution=1000)
et.ras <-rasterize(spdf, r, field=paste0("m",1:ncol(spdf)))
```

This will create a single RasterLayer with a Raster Attribute Table. To create a RasterStack, do:

```
s <- deratify(et.ras)
```

If you were to use a loop, use `rasterize` only once, the get the polygon IDs, and then use `subs` for the actual variables of interest.

And of course this saves you the pain of external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. The speed improved dramatically ( few hours to few minutes).

Comment: As always Robert, you provide a lot of food for thought (in such a good way). I'd not thought of the approach you outlined, and indeed I think it would improve performance in some of my use cases over issuing multiple calls to `gdal_rasterize`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As of March 2020, you can now consider this new package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/vignettes/using-fasterize.html

```
fasterize()
```

Works exactly as

```
rasterize()
```

But 100-1000 times faster. I think this can help a lots of people.